# How to combine all sublist elements into one list

Tags: r, list

I have a list (of length 3) which is made up of sublists (each of differing length - 2, 2, 3). I would like to store all of this as one big list (e.g., no sublists - just one list of length 7). I understand how to do it manually, but is there a function or command I can use?

I would like to be able to do this for lists and sublists of any length.

Here's an example of the list:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
      name  n       l_1         t         t_3          t_4          t_5 cluster
12  563035 19  9.263158 0.2017045  0.06379453  0.075876830  0.095852895       1
14  563037 19  8.026316 0.2076503  0.05634675  0.098684211 -0.104566563       1


[[1]][[2]]
      name  n       l_1         t         t_3          t_4          t_5 cluster
13  563036 20  7.200000 0.1838450 -0.06428098  0.085681987 -0.011070830       2
17  563042 20  7.725000 0.2168285  0.15161037  0.117570045 -0.067102568       2


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
      name  n       l_1          t          t_3          t_4           t_5 cluster
1   561101 11  6.772727 0.19731544  0.029478458 -0.128117914  6.235828e-02       1
44  563080 11  7.545455 0.18554217  0.103896104  0.285714286 -2.164502e-02       1


[[2]][[2]]
      name  n       l_1         t         t_3           t_4          t_5 cluster
48  566017 33 10.400000 0.2037624  0.16432326  0.1166006937 -0.012830017       2
49  566018 22  9.218182 0.2113271  0.30646667  0.2502280702  0.189838207       2
50  566020 19 11.736842 0.3111609  0.51217445  0.5147883012  0.462723120       2


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
      name  n       l_1         t         t_3         t_4         t_5 cluster
158 568004 18  8.722222 0.1787186 -0.05083857  0.06498952  0.06918239       1
161 568046 19 11.794737 0.3646190  0.54582540  0.49747236  0.32255755       1
162 568047 18 12.916667 0.3366224  0.53523112  0.40464111  0.29960541       1
163 568048 20 11.590000 0.3918986  0.50007725  0.43039556  0.34299752       1


[[3]][[2]]
      name  n       l_1         t         t_3        t_4         t_5 cluster
165 568050 20  9.125000 0.2034607  0.29789747 0.31073776  0.09157738       2
167 568054 20  8.850000 0.1332144  0.09895833 0.18636204  0.04641544       2



[[3]][[3]]
      name  n       l_1         t         t_3          t_4          t_5 cluster
168 568058 20  8.675000 0.2012741  0.18161266  0.200319163 -0.009375416       3
170 568061 18 24.861111 0.7394676  0.91836281  0.928317483  0.905563950       3
```

Many thanks,
Sylvia

Comment: Do you mean like `unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE)` (where "mylist" is the name of your list)?

Comment: Yes, thank you so very much for your help. That is exactly what I was after. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnandaMahto if you do not post it as an answer, I will ;).

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, answer posted :)

Comment: +1 For somehow not being a duplicate, and for choosing a good title.

Comment: I've posted some sample data to recreate the data in this question [here](http://pastebin.com/FtLfC7vY).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For your specific question, the answer is simple:

```
unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE)
```

However, you asked how to be able to do this for a list with an arbitrary number of sublists. That is a bit more tricky. Fortunately, an Akhil S Bhel has tackled that problem for us and created a function called `LinearizeNestedList`. His site is down at the moment, but I had put his function up [as a Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/4205477).

First, we'll create some sample data with nested lists within nested lists.

```
NList <- list(a = "a", # Atom
              b = 1:5, # Vector
              c = data.frame(x = runif(5), y = runif(5)), 
              d = matrix(runif(4), nrow = 2), 
              e = list(l = list("a", "b"), 
                       m = list(1:5, 5:10),
                       n = list(list(1), list(2))))
```

The source list looks like this. Notice the nesting that happens with the nested list item "e".

```
NList
# $a
# [1] "a"
# 
# $b
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $c
#           x          y
# 1 0.7893562 0.47761962
# 2 0.0233312 0.86120948
# 3 0.4772301 0.43809711
# 4 0.7323137 0.24479728
# 5 0.6927316 0.07067905
# 
# $d
#            [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.09946616 0.5186343
# [2,] 0.31627171 0.6620051
# 
# $e
# $e$l
# $e$l[[1]]
# [1] "a"
# 
# $e$l[[2]]
# [1] "b"
# 
# 
# $e$m
# $e$m[[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $e$m[[2]]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# 
# $e$n
# $e$n[[1]]
# $e$n[[1]][[1]]
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# $e$n[[2]]
# $e$n[[2]][[1]]
# [1] 2
```

You can see how `LinearizeNestedList` "flattens" all sublists so you end up with a single list.

```
LinearizeNestedList(NList)
# $a
# [1] "a"
# 
# $b
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $c
#           x          y
# 1 0.7893562 0.47761962
# 2 0.0233312 0.86120948
# 3 0.4772301 0.43809711
# 4 0.7323137 0.24479728
# 5 0.6927316 0.07067905
# 
# $d
#            [,1]      [,2]
# [1,] 0.09946616 0.5186343
# [2,] 0.31627171 0.6620051
# 
# $`e/l/1`
# [1] "a"
# 
# $`e/l/2`
# [1] "b"
# 
# $`e/m/1`
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5
# 
# $`e/m/2`
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# $`e/n/1/1`
# [1] 1
# 
# $`e/n/2/1`
# [1] 2
```

---

By the way, I forgot to mention that you can flatten `data.frame`s in `list`s too (since a `data.frame` is a special type of `list` in R.

If you really want to flatten everything out (well, except arrays, since they are just vectors with `dim`s), add `LinearizeDataFrames = TRUE` to your `LinearizeNestedList` call:

```
LinearizeNestedList(NList, LinearizeDataFrames=TRUE)
```

Comment: Dear Ananda, thank you very much for your excellent reply. These both work perfectly for what I require. Again, many thanks for the prompt reply. Sylvia

Comment: @user2853331, if this fully answers your question, do consider "accepting" it by clicking on the empty arrow to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thank you Ananda. Yes it does fully answer my question. This is my first post so I didn't know how to accept your answer. I have done this now. Sylvia

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
dissolve <- function(x){
  operator <- function(x){
    if(is.list(x)){
      for(i in seq(x)){
        operator(x[[i]])
      }
    }else{
      combi[[length(combi)+1]] <<- x
    }
  }
  combi=list()
  operator(x)
  return(combi)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

.... does `unlist(mylist)` work?

Comment: Thank you very much! I used  unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE) as one of the commenters above mentioned and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: That does not maintain the sublists as list items. You need the `recursive = FALSE` step.

Comment: @AnandaMahto But the OP wants "no sublists - just one list of length 7)".

Comment: @HongOoi, sorry to down-vote, but this is simply a wrong answer as it is.

Comment: @HongOoi, get some sample data from [here](http://pastebin.com/FtLfC7vY) and compare `unlist(mylist)` with `unlist(mylist, recursive = FALSE)` or `LinearizeNestedList(mylist)`, and do the same for `NList` (also included in the pastebin link).